# How to resolve error "No runtime specified. WLS Web Service projects require a runtime to be present for most tooling." when publishing my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I spend one day trying to fix this issue, and finally found a solution. As Google doesn't have any answer for this Eclipse error, I thought of putting this for everyone.

Issue:
When I try to publish project via eclipse, I'm getting this error message:

> No runtime specified.  WLS Web Service projects require a runtime to be present for most tooling.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: While posting a question and an own answer is appreciated, you should actually post the answer as one and accept as soon as you can (takes two or three days). Thus, others can easily recognize the solution as such.

Comment: Also added relevant tags. But please do as @JensErat suggests, or this will get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!! This was my first post so made some mistake, but i will make sure to follow this next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Credits go to Akshay who originally posted this solution in his question.)*

This error message appears if your target runtime is not set to the Weblogic version you are using.

The fix is pretty simple, just follow these steps:

1. Right click on your <kbd>Project Folder</kbd>, then <kbd>Properties</kbd>
2. Select <kbd>Target Runtimes</kbd>
3. Once you select you will see the WebLogic version you have added for your project
4. Just activate the checkbox and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>
5. Done - your error should be gone